# How do I combine these two tables so I have one which  displays both State and Zip code?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have two queries that find both the Zip codes, and the States for all the respondents in our database. Here they are

For ZIP code:

```
select top 100  S.ID as SurveyID, S.SID, S.SurveyNumber, S.ABCSurveyName, SE.RespondentID, Q.name as QuestionName, rp.Condition as ZipCode
from Surveys S 
    join Sessions SE 
        on S.id = SE.SurveyID 
    join RespondentProfiles rp
        on RP.RespondentID = SE.RespondentID
    join Questions Q 
        on Q.ID = rp.QuestionID
where q.name = 'ZIP'
        and S.ID = 13900
        and Q.LK_RecordStatusID = 1
```

For state:

```
select VW.ID as SurveyID, VW.SID, SurveyNumber, ABCSurveyName, RespondentID, VW.Name as QuestionName, st.Code as State
from (
    select top 100 S.ID, S.SID, S.SurveyNumber, S.ABCSurveyName, SE.RespondentID, Q.name, rp.Condition 
    from Surveys S 
        join Sessions SE 
            on S.id = SE.SurveyID 
        join RespondentProfiles rp
            on RP.RespondentID = SE.RespondentID
        join Questions Q 
            on Q.ID = rp.QuestionID
    where S.ID = 13900
            and q.name = 'STATE'
            and Q.LK_RecordStatusID = 1

) VW
    join LK_States st
        on st.ID = vw.Condition
```

This works, but I'd like to have them all in one table, i.e. Zip Code and State.

Thanks!

questions schema:

Column_name Type    Computed    Length  Prec    Scale   Nullable

```
TrimTrailingBlanks  FixedLenNullInSource    Collation
ID  int no  4   10      0       no  (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
SID nvarchar    no  128                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
Name    nvarchar    no  64                  yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
QuestionIdentifier  nvarchar    no  128                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
ParentID    int no  4   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
LK_QuestionTypeID   int no  4   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
LK_QuestionCategoryID   int no  4   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
LK_IndustryID   int no  4   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
OptionMask  nvarchar    no  512                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
MetaTags    ntext   no  16                  yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
Order   int no  4   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
Rows    int no  4   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
Columns int no  4   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
IsDisplay   bit no  1                   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
AnswerLifespan  int no  4   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
CreateUserID    int no  4   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
CreateDate  datetime    no  8                   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
UpdateUserID    int no  4   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
UpdateDate  datetime    no  8                   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
LK_RecordStatusID   bit no  1                   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
LK_QuestionClassID  int no  4   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
LK_QuestionVisibilityID int no  4   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
DisplayLK_QuestionTypeID    int no  4   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
```

Comment: I'm guessin this is straightforwd but i'm missin in

Comment: Can you describe the purpose of table 'Questions' in your queries. Also a generic description of your schema would help.

Comment: @nicholas - I've added the schema

Comment: Which tables do the zip codes originate from and which table do the states originate from? also, what is the purpose of the 'Questions' table?

Comment: You show that you're using `rp.Condition` as ZipCode, and already joining to that table in the state query. Why not just include that column there? Additionally, why are the queries for these two so different? It appears that you would get different sets of respondents.

Comment: @Adel - It appears that the only differentiating factor is the Q.NAME column, is that correct?

Comment: @RobB - Let me check, I'm not sure atm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I did not take time to remove unnecessary selected fields but here is an ugly query that should get pretty close. Essentially your 'State' query was recasting most of the joins as a sub query anyway:

```
SELECT ... FROM
(SELECT ... FROM ... JOIN ... JOIN ... WHERE Q.Name = 'State') VW
JOIN LK_States ...
```

All I did was add an extra sub-query to join on at the top level. I think there may be a more efficient query but since it is a `SELECT TOP 100`, I'm not sure performance will be an issue.

```
SELECT ... FROM
(SELECT ... FROM ... JOIN ... JOIN ... WHERE Q.Name = 'State') VW
JOIN
(SELECT ... FROM ... JOIN ... JOIN ... WHERE Q.Name = 'Zip') VW2
ON VW2.SurveyID = VW.SurveyID
JOIN LK_States ...
```

Not checked for errors but here is the entire monster:

```
select VW.SurveyID as SurveyID, VW.SID, VW.SurveyNumber, VW.FEDSurveyName, VW.RespondentID, VW.Name as QuestionName, st.Code as State, VW2.Condition as ZipCode
from (
    select top 100 S.ID as SurveyID, S.SID, S.SurveyNumber, S.FEDSurveyName, SE.RespondentID, Q.name, rp.Condition 
    from Surveys S 
        join Sessions SE 
            on S.id = SE.SurveyID 
        join RespondentProfiles rp
            on RP.RespondentID = SE.RespondentID
        join Questions Q 
            on Q.ID = rp.QuestionID
    where S.ID = 13900
            and q.name = 'STATE'
            and Q.LK_RecordStatusID = 1

    ) VW
    join (
    select top 100  S.ID as SurveyID, S.SID, S.SurveyNumber, S.FEDSurveyName, SE.RespondentID, Q.name, rp.Condition
    from Surveys S 
        join Sessions SE 
            on S.id = SE.SurveyID 
        join RespondentProfiles rp
            on RP.RespondentID = SE.RespondentID
        join Questions Q 
            on Q.ID = rp.QuestionID
    where q.name = 'ZIP'
            and S.ID = 13900
            and Q.LK_RecordStatusID = 1
    ) VW2
        on VW2.SurveyID = VW.SurveyID
    join LK_States st
        on st.ID = vw.Condition
```

Comment: `Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 28
Ambiguous column name 'SurveyNumber'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 28
Ambiguous column name 'FEDSurveyName'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 28
Ambiguous column name 'RespondentID'.`

Comment: Fixed it. Careful, this is starting to get too specific / tech support - questions need to stay generic.

Comment: Thank you so much Nicholas - I am indebted. And yes you're right that I should avoid getting  too specific

Answer (score 2):

Without undertstanding fully your structure, try the following:

```
select top 100 
    S.ID, 
    S.SID, 
    S.SurveyNumber, 
    S.FEDSurveyName, 
    SE.RespondentID, 
    qState.name as QuestionName, 
    rp.Condition as ZipCode, 
    st.Code as State
from [Surveys] S
    inner join [Sessions] SE 
        on S.id = SE.SurveyID 
    inner join [RespondentProfiles] rp
        on RP.RespondentID = SE.RespondentID
    inner join [Questions] qState
        on qState.ID = rp.QuestionID
    inner join [Questions] qZip 
        on qZip.ID = rp.QuestionID
    inner join [LK_States] st
        on st.ID = rp.Condition
where 
    S.ID = 13900
    and qState.name = 'STATE'
    and qZip.name = 'ZIP'
    and qState.LK_RecordStatusID = 1
```

Comment: Do I just surround both with it?

Comment: UNION is placed in between the two queries

Comment: OK I tried this, but it's not combining them horizontally - I'd like any given row to say Zipcode + state

Comment: @RobB - added an edit with an example call, if you're amenable.